# Include simple sound in iphone app

Tags: ios4, core-audio, avaudioplayer, openal

I searched many questions - but no one seems to be giving simplest, most uniform approach, hence please do not close as duplicate.

My requirement is simple: I have quiz app.

I want to include:

> 1. background music that plays continually - probably more than one
>      audio.
> 2. I need occassional sounds played at specific events - they
>          are very short in duration. Maybe 4-5 in number.

What sound format do I use? [aac etc]

How do I produce it? (optionally, get it from internet, if free)

What is the best approach to incorporate it? [audioplayback, openal etc)

Forgive me if this is quite stupid, but I am going very generic here and can't seem to find it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sound format, use AAC or uncompressed 16-bit little endian in a CAF container (avoid mp3 since it's difficult to make it loop cleanly). You can convert using the command line tool 'afconvert':

Compressed:

```
afconvert -f caff -d aac sourcefile.wav destfile.caf
```

Uncompressed 16-bit:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 sourcefile.wav destfile.caf
```

For production, either record it yourself (using an audio program such as Audacity), get a professional to do it, or buy royalty free sounds/music.

To incorporate it, use AVAudioPlayer for music and OpenAL for sounds. OpenAL is difficult to use and doesn't decode compressed audio on its own, so you may want to use an audio library such as https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

Comment: thanks Karl, I appreciate the approach suggested. As for content, where should I look for free sounds? How can I ensure if they are royalty free? I have seen that even where content is marked 'free', it requires some kind of attribution, I don't know how to do it, and would prefer totally free content over it.

Comment: you could try freesound.org. lots of great samples and some with no issues in terms of use. may i also suggest, to make your own. it probably will take you about the same time.

Comment: ubu.com is a huge portal of free open source sound and audio generally

Comment: thanks soh-la, do you know of any resources that will create me files that are directly usable in my app? Like without much conversion involved and would still be of the best quality?

Comment: @EventHorizon, ubu.com seems to be huge source of vintage audio. But I doubt I can find downloadable content. And maybe, I just want to doublecheck if its truly royalty-free. Thanks anyway for showing a great place!

Comment: You're best off just paying for sound effects. They're not really that expensive in the end. Either buy a royalty free DVD or get them piecemeal from a place like http://www.sounddogs.com. For music, you can find royalty free music from places like http://luckylionstudios.com/royalty-free-video-game-music-library